# Just switched from windows 10 to Ubuntu. Right before I uninstalled windows, all three of my monitors were working, now one is black screen

Tags: display, hardware, monitor

When picking the primary display, all three monitors are there. It appears my left monitor it still part of the equation, because certain windows open up over there, and I can drag the mouse into the void. Not really sure what to look up to fix this. Any help would be appreciated.